# Eclipse relative ClassPath question

Tags: eclipse, classpath

New Eclipse user here with a quick question:

I tried changing the following line in my workspace .classpath file to solve a build error that cannot find a referenced project.

```
<classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/EventNotifier"/>
```

to

```
 <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="../EventNotifier"/>
```

After doing this, I get the following error:

Illegal entry in '.classpath' of project 'occ600server' file: Path for IClasspathEntry must be absolute

Referenced folder in not in same directory as .classpath file but one level up.  How do I fix this?

TIA.

Comment: The `/` references back to the root of your workspace. Don't you have a project named `EventNotifier`?

Comment: No.  Project EventNotifier is one level higher than Workspace root.  I just imported this project into Workspace and that has solved problem. Thanks.

Comment: please make sure to provide (your own) answer and close the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a classpath variable for this purpose.

- Go to the workspace preferences, Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables
- Create a new variable named WORKSPACE_ROOT (or whatever)
- Use a `<classpathentry ... />` of type `var` and put your variable at the start of the path attribute without any fancy `${}` business.

Like so:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="WORKSPACE_ROOT/project/lib/somelibrary.jar" />
```

This technique is used by `mvn eclipse:eclipse` among other things.

Comment: This is nice. Thank you.

Just found a minor problem for me: In eclipse, when I find a class. it will include everything from the Workspace_root too, which shows duplicates as other classes. Do you have a quick solution for this?  Thanks again for the help.