# .classpath file issues when cloning Java eclipse project from git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, classpath

I believe there may be an issue in our .classpath file. We are experiencing issues where we have to tell eclipse each time where to find our .jar files everytime we downlaod our java project onto a new laptop.

I noticed in my .classpath it's pointing to a specific place on my laptop. Is there a way to change the .classpath or .project correctly so we don't have to update it manually each time?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/5"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/openNLPThemeProject2"/>
    <classpathentry combineaccessrules="false" kind="src" path="/API"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/info/Documents/myproject/Thesaurus2WithGUI/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Below is our .project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>Thesaurus2WithGUI</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Look at using Classpath Variables - see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392852/2670892)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your source organized as an Eclipse project (instead of Maven, Gradle, etc.) I suggest to use [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) for taking care of dependencies to external libraries.

1. Install IvyDE plugin from [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/apache-ivyde%E2%84%A2).
2. Add a file `ivy.xml` in the project root folder

```xml
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
  <info organisation="com.your.organization" module="Thesaurus2WithGUI" status="release" />
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.jsoup" name="jsoup" rev="1.12.1"/>     
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

3. Replace this `.classpath` row

```
<classpathentry kind="lib"
  path="C:/Users/info/Documents/myproject/Thesaurus2WithGUI/lib/jsoup-1.12.1.jar"/>
```

with this one

```xml
<classpathentry kind="con"
path="org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.cpcontainer.IVYDE_CONTAINER/?project=Thesaurus2WithGUI&amp;ivyXmlPath=ivy.xml&amp;confs=*"/>
```

4. Refresh (F5) the project.